# Bulk upload of data based on a template in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

We have a web application where users can create certain type of records from a web page. There are many mandatory fields on the webform and users will need to fill all in order to save the data.

Now we need to provide a functionality to users so that they can download a MS Excel template or other template and user will provide bulk data based on the format provided.

Did you guys ever do anything of this sort. Any ideas greatly appreciated.

My main concern with the above approach is that we need to validate the data user provides in the Excel sheet. Are there any 3rd party tools/Components that do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have the client upload the excel file. Open it as a data source, validate the data (DataTable object). If there are any errors, return a list of errors to the user. You can do this all in .NET